# What's meant by "isSome oldest(tl dates)" here; why "oldest(tl dates)" has a option type?

Tags: sml

```
fun oldest (dates: (int*int*int) list) =
    if null dates
    then NONE
    else let
    val ans = oldest(tl dates)
    in
    if isSome ans andalso is_older(valOf ans, hd dates)
    then ans
    else SOME (hd dates)
    end
```

a function compares all dates(like 2018,2,28) in the list, and get the oldest date

Comment: Consider the case `oldest []`. What could its result be, if not of an option type?

Comment: It should be a list, but "isSome list" will cause an error

Comment: No, it can't be a list – the oldest date is not a list, it is a date. The point of the option type is that sometimes, what you're looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: I can not understand. if it's a date, it should be a type list as defined in the parenthesis, and " isSome an expression" is effective only when the type of expression is an option, but why the ans has an option type

Comment: In my point of view, I have to add "SOME" to make sth become an option type.

Comment: The result of `oldest`  is an option type;  the type of `oldest` is  `(int * int * int) list -> (int * int * int) option`. Thus, `ans` is an `(int * int * int) option`.

Comment: thx. I think I might make mistakes on a very basic level so that I can not understand that